# Question about the definition of topological entropy (book: Brin & Stuck)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems, limsup-and-liminf, topological-dynamics

For a compact metric space $(X,d)$ and a continuous map $f\colon X\to X$, the book *Introduction to Dynamical Systems* written by M. Brin and G. Stuck uses the expression $$h_{\varepsilon}(f):=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\log(\text{cov}(n,\varepsilon,f))$$ in their definition of topological entropy. Later they prove that you can replace limsup by lim, because apparently the lim of the sequence above converges to a finite number. So why do they use the limsup in their definition? I thought that the limsup may also diverge to infinity.

Comment: What is the meaning of “cov”?

Comment: @FShrike It's the minimum cardinality of an open cover each of whose elements have diameter less than $\epsilon$ with respect to the Bowen metric $d_n^f$ (e.g. as mentioned here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4345039/169085).

Comment: See e.g. https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~jack/DYNOTES/dn7.pdf , p. 7-8 for further details.

Comment: (To be more accurate perhaps I should drop "open".)

Comment: @AlpUzman Thank you for the reference

Answer (score 2):

Probably because any sequence $x_n$ in $\mathbb R$ (so also $x_n = \log(\operatorname{cov}(n,\varepsilon,f)$) (for some fixed $f$, $\varepsilon$) has a *well-defined* $\limsup$ (which can be $+\infty$). So first you have a well-defined (extended) number and then you can discuss its other properties, like whether it's always finite etc.

Comment: What is the meaning of “cov”