# Prove that the topological entropy of an isometry is zero.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems, entropy, ergodic-theory

Let $T$ be the isometry of a metric compact with a dense orbit.
Prove that the topological entropy $T$ is zero.

What happened now:
$T$ is the isometry of a metric compact, that is, for any two
points of a compact with metric d, we have $d(T(a), T(b)) = d(a, b)$.
Since by the condition with a dense orbit, then $T$ is a topologically transitive map. We have that
$d(T^
i
(a), T^i
(b)) = . . . = d(T
^2
(a), T^2
(b)) = d(T(a), T(b)) = d(a, b) $.
Help to prove.  Happy New Year)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
There are multiple ways of calculating/defining topological entropy, in particular there are ways of calculating it via the so-called Bowen metrics (I mentioned these metrics in a previous answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4326733/169085). Say we want to use the spanning numbers w/r/t Bowen metrics. We'll need to take the logarithm of the $(n,\epsilon)$-spanning number; divide it by $n$ and then take limits. But observe that since the transformation is an isometry these spanning numbers are independent of $n$, as you've observed.

(Also, this statement is true without the point transitivity assumption.)

Comment: Solve $N_n(\epsilon)$ - the number of points of the minimum epsilon network for $(X, d_n)$. Then the entropy has the form $h(T) = lim_{ε\to0} lim sup_{n\to∞}
\frac{ln(N(\epsilon ))}{n}$ Because the transformation is an isometry, independent of n. Therefore, with n go to infinity, the entropy is 0.

Comment: It seems to be solved this way

Comment: Add: $d_{n}(a, b)=\max \left\{d\left(T^{i} (a), T^{i} (b)\right), i=0,1, \ldots ., n-1\right\}$